# Java and Kotlin interoperability, managing data using Koltin Lambda?

Tags: java, sqlite, kotlin, arraylist

So essentially, I am using java to obtain information, and then I am using Kotlin to manage the information. So what I have done so far is, I have stored my information into a ArrayList called `tableData` in java, I store all my elements into this list (I should have used a better name here) and then returned the list. My java code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> readAllData () {
    //Connecting to database
    Connection con = DbConnection.connect();
    //Preparing statement
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    //result set declaration
    ResultSet rs = null;
    //tableData String array
    ArrayList<String> tableData = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            //Database initialization
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM ProjectInfo";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                //for each iteration store the data into variable a from column projectName
                String a = rs.getString("projectName");
                //print out each element
                //System.out.println("a = " + a);
                tableData.add(a);
            }
            //other catch exceptions
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
                ps.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e){
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
    //System.out.println(tableData);
        //return all the data that has been stored into this array
        return tableData;
    }
```

In Kotlin, I created a property class called `GettingData` and passed one parameter `projectName: ArrayList<String>`. Then i moved onto actually printing out the data

```
class GettingData(var projectName: ArrayList<String>) {
}

fun ManageData() {

    var arrayData = listOf<GettingData>(GettingData(DbConnection.readAllData()))
    var projectNameData = arrayData.map {it.projectName}

    for (projectName in projectNameData) {
        println(projectName)
    }

}
```

All my elements are printed out, however I cannot use the filter functions to call specific elements from the arrayList? I want to be able to call every element and print them out in a alphabetical order? I tried `filter, sortedWith and find` functions but I cannot seem to get it working. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question boils down to wanting to print a list of strings in alphabetical order.

You can use the [`sorted()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted.html) function:

```
for (projectName in projectNameData.sorted()) {
    println(projectName)
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but it simply gives me an error, and tells me to create a extension functions in context actions, which I am not too sure about?

Comment: OK, then I don't think your question is answerable in its current form. Please try to reduce it to the minimal reproducible code required, and include the desired behaviour and any error messages you get. For example, the entire Java section doesn't seem relevant to the question. The above code works for me and prints out the sorted list, so there must be something else going on in your case.

Comment: It worked! I figured that a lot of the items in my database where left null or empty, this was causing the issue. It is working now!